# LED Circuit turns on or off after pulse of varying intensity

Tags: led, circuit-design, flipflop

I'm trying to make a circuit that turns a LED on or off by using a pulse voltage. The LED should turn on with a pulse of intensity A and off with a pulse of B, where A and B < 5V. Most of the time, this voltage will be null. Two additional constant DC voltage sources can be used.

I've thought about using OpAmps to determine whether the pulse is high or low enough, but the LED should only change states *after* the pulse, and it should stay in this new state until a new pulse happens.

What basic components (resistors, capacitors, inductors, OpAmps, diodes, MOSFETs) could be used to maintain the LED on after a pulse and have it off only after another pulse of different intensity?

Comment: You may want to look at using a flip-flop or latch; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your question, this circuit might help you:

[image: Divid-by-two triggerable bistable bipolar transistor circuit from Nuts and Volts]

It is from Nuts & Volts magazine, and part of their [Bipolar Transistor Cookbook](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_6), an eight part tutorial worth going through.

You would feed the output of Q (or not-Q) into a circuit that turns on your LED.